# MyImage.Source index is not changing with the list

Tags: c#, image, xamarin.forms, indexing

Could someone help me with an index issue. The line for **MyImage.Source** was added and it does not seem to be updating the images in the list. The text is updaing just fine. How do I get the index from **GrapplingGuard[ndx].ImageA** to update the image?

Originally the **GrapplingGuard[ndx].ImageA** was **GrapplingGuard[0]** however I assume that I need to indicate that it should relate to [ndx]. ImageAI have tried to move the line after the Binding Context but that did not change anything. Do I need to include something in the OnButtonClicked section?

```
public partial class BGGrappling : ContentPage
{
    List<GrapplingGuard> GrapplingGuard { get; set; }

    int ndx = 0;

    public BGGrappling()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GrapplingGuard = new List<GrapplingGuard>
        {
            new GrapplingGuard
            {
                TitleText = "Long Guard",
                EngText = "Eng Text 1",
                ItText = "IT Text 1",
                PageNo = "1/4",
                ImageA = "HemaSwordFiore.Images.BGGrapple.LongGuard.png"
            },
            new GrapplingGuard
            {
                TitleText = "Boar's Tooth",
                EngText = "Eng Text 2",
                ItText = "IT Text 2",
                PageNo = "2/4",
                ImageA = "HemaSwordFiore.Images.BGGrapple.BoardsTooth.png"
            }
        };

        //[ndx] not changing image from list
        MyImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource(GrapplingGuard[ndx].ImageA, typeof(BGGrappling).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

        BindingContext = GrapplingGuard[ndx];
    }
    async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ndx++;

        if (ndx < GrapplingGuard.Count && ndx <= 3)
        {
            BindingContext = GrapplingGuard[ndx];
        }
        else
        {
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: For the MyImage control, do you set the source directly or set the source with binding in xaml?  If you use the binding, have you use the INotifyPropertyChanged to update? If you set the source directly, have you set the build action to embeded resource?

Comment: Hi @WendyZang-MSFT, I do have a binding in the xaml side (x:Name="MyImage"). I have added the INotifyPropertyChanged but it needs to be set to the list **List<GrapplingGuard> GrapplingGuard** since that is what is updaing but I keep getting an error that the PropertyChange?.Invoke must be before += or -+

Comment: Could you provide more details with code for me to reproduce?

Comment: Hi @WendyZang-MSFT, I did the following for the MyImage string since that is what the guide did on the MS site on Databinding, but no luck: 
 **
 public string MyImage 
        { 
            get => MyImage;
            set
            {
                MyImage = value;

                var args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MyImage));

                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
            }
        }**

Comment: If it is possible, could you provide the code sample for me to reproduce? You could upload on github or other drives and give me the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to add the `MyImage.Source` line in the incrementing section

```
async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ndx++;

    if (ndx < GrapplingGuard.Count && ndx <= 3)
    {
        BindingContext = GrapplingGuard[ndx];
    }
    else
    {
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
    ...
}
```